# Empty email to Yahoo users with Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, yahoo

i try to send email to yahoo users when they register in my website, but the email is empty.

So i tried to edit the Email class and put send_multipart variable to FALSE. but nothing changed.

i use my smtp server and on other email clients, everything works perfectly.

Any idea?

i send email like this:

```
$email_content = array(
'email' => $email,
'subject' => lang('email_subject'),
'template' => 'auth/email/email_template'
);

$this->send_mail($email_content);
```

the email template:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>title</h1>
<p>welcome, this is a test message</p>
</body>
</html>
```

in yahoo mailbox, i see:

```
<h1></h1>
<p></p>
```

and my send_mail function:

```
public function send_mail($data)
{
    $this->load->library('email');

    $message = $this->load->view($data['template'], $data, true);
    $this->email->from('no-reply@mysite.com', 'Mysite.com');
    $this->email->to($data['email']);
    $this->email->subject('Mysite.com - ' . $data['subject']);
    $this->email->message($message);
    if ($this->email->send())
    {
        return true;
    }else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: why this negative value?

Comment: Advice? Sure. When asking questions, be sure to include all the information required for people to give you good, useful answers. Without any code, any detailed explanation of what is supposed to happen and what is happening...you're unlikely to get responses.

Comment: What is the content of the email?  What do you see if you look at the source of the email in Yahoo (https://luxsci.com/blog/viewing-the-message-source-full-headers-of-an-email.html)?

Comment: just edited my initial post

Answer (score 0):

set the mail type to html:

```
$this->load->library('email');
// set mail type with this line: 
$this->email->set_mailtype( 'html' );
```